# Is it possible to rerender the head part asynchronously (JSF2/Ajax/Richfaces)

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, ajax4jsf

I'm dynamically including some composite components into my page, which contain css declarations within separate files. My problem is that the page is only rendered partially through an ajax call so the head isn't rerendered or updated but I will not rerender the whole page everytime, when I'm including the components.

If tried to rerender the head part using `<h:head id="head"/>` within my template and/or my facelet root page and rerender this part with `<a4j:ajax render="head"/>` but this doesn't seem to work.

Is there a possibilly of rerendering the head part without reloading the whole page?

Comment: It isn't possible as you encountered yourself. You might want to rewrite the question to ask about the functional requirement instead of about a possible solution which isn't a viable solution after all.

Comment: Damn, I had already feared about that. So I think I've to include these CSS files dynamically through DOM manipulation.

Comment: @BalusC Perhaps you would answer the question, that it is possible to rate your helpful answers! ..only if you want to! Thanks!

Comment: I've re-read your question once again. Are you using `<h:outputStylesheet>` in the `<cc:implementation>` or not?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `<h:outputStylesheet>` within `<cc:implementation>`.

Answer (score 0):

Directly rendering the HEAD tag would mean to re-render the AJAX-Script jsf.js itself. This would lead to undesired result, such as a script loop.

There is an AJAX extension to track the header scripts on each view and insert them dynamically. The solution is part of the Extension "JSF Ext".